# Perfect Scroll bar error no element is specified to initialize PerfectScrollbar on windows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, windows, perfect-scrollbar

I am getting this error on server start on react js.

Error: no element is specified to initialize PerfectScrollbar

However it is working fine on friend MAC OS. I am using windows.

I am using this version:
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.4.0",

Answer (score 6):

Quite old question but I'll post my solution since I had the same problem. I was having the same error message:

```
Error: no element is specified to initialize PerfectScrollbar
```

In my case, it seems that I was calling PerfectScrollbar on an element that didn't exist. I had:

```
const asideBody = new PerfectScrollbar('.aside-body', {
    suppressScrollX: true
});
```

And I was having the error in the pages I didn't have any element in the DOM with class="aside-body".

So I managed to only call PerfectScrollbar in the appropriate pages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that was the issue that i was calling PerfectScrollbar on an element that didn't exist.
I know its not a proper solution but i removed these errors by giving those undefined classes to an empty span.
So now it does not bother me any more.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to add condition on the calling function verifying element is defined